# Python обработка файлов

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Всем привет, есть хостинг хранящий метеоданные. Данные записаны в виде файла, продолжительностью 10 минут, информация в двоичном виде с определенной последовательностью(прим.размер 600кб). Проблема заключается в том , что мне надо обработать , файлы за один год (если файлы у нас по 10 минут то за 1 ч - 6 файлов ,За 24 ч - 144 файлов , За месяц примерно 4464 файла , За год 53 568 файлов).
Я работаю с библиотеками numpy , pandas на начальном уровне. Как обработать такое большое количество файлов а именно из каждого файла вынести среднее значение за каждые 10 минут потом объединить среднее значение за 1 ч , за 24 ч , за месяц , за год и так далее. Чтобы можно было составить инфографику за целый год?

Comment: _Проблема заключается в том, что мне надо обработать_ - это задача, а проблема в чем? Если это постфактум обработка (тем более за год), то не принципиально, наверное, будет она продолжаться 10 минут или 1 час.

Comment: а в чем проблема их загрузить на жд и потом работать с ними?

Comment: @mkkik а как возможно реализовать этот алгоритм ? может быть у вас есть примеры.

Comment: @garrythehotdog в условиях к работе стоит онлайн загрузка

Comment: Что именно вызывает у вас трудности?

Comment: сколько мегабайт необходимо загрузить?